# Reading int from plist file in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, plist, nsdictionary

I need some help with reading from a plist file.
This is my code, but it's not working and I don't have ideas anymore. I want to build a dylib that read the integer of this plist com.mi.pp1.plist.

```
Bux = [[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.mi.pp1.plist"]valueForKey:@"kBux"]intValue];

%hook PPPlayerData
- (int)bux
{
    return Bux;
}
%end
```

Comment: Is this meant for jailbroken devices? Normal apps running on normal devices can't access such a file.

Comment: Yes . I am not sure if I can create dylibs for non jail broken .

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Logos#.25hook

Comment: With this you can hook to processes .

Comment: You should be calling `objectForKey:`, not `valueForKey:`.

Comment: Thanks worked , but now it's int=0.

Comment: That probably means the key isn't in the dictionary. Do yourself a favor and split that line up into three. Then you can see what is in the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks that was not the problem , since I use 3 plist to check the value I had to change the key in every plist .

Answer (score 0):

```
int Bux;

Bux = [[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences    /com.mi.pp1.plist"]objectForKey:@"kBux"]intValue];

%hook PPPlayerData
- (int)bux
{
return Bux;
}
```

works